# In Shiny, How to add iconic checkboxgroup input to create datatable, based on the selection, which contain icons on the column names not text?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have created this app which contains datatable with icons or logos on the column names. Each step separately is doable but the issue is in executing them altogether. I am ok if it's not doable to add images to checkboxes but adding images to the datatables is necessary

the issue here I can't merge them to get the result as 
checkboxes with logos "without text if possible" to control the number of columns which also contains only logos on the column names

here are the images for each step 
[image]
[image]
[image]
and here is the [*dataset*](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q2YNlrkus-Qls45wSZGl0p-LoPDyu7rm)

```
    library(shiny)
    library(data.table)

    ui <- fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("myTable"))

    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      logoList = data.frame(
    name = c("opel", "kia", "bmw"),
    logo = c(
      "<img height='50' title= 'opel'     src='https://i.wheelsage.org/pictures/opel/autowp.ru_opel_logo_1.jpg'></img>",
      "<img height='50' src='https://www.logospng.com/images/88/royal-azure-    blue-kia-icon-free-car-logo-88484.png'></img>",
      "<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/bmw-    4-202746.png'></img>" ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    myData = reactiveVal( {
    logo_name_match <- merge(
      x = data.frame(
        row_id = 1:length(colnames(testmatrixnew)),
        cols = colnames(testmatrixnew), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
      y = logoList, 
      by.x = "cols", 
      by.y = "name", 
      all.x = TRUE)
     logo_name_match <- logo_name_match[with(logo_name_match, order(row_id)),]
     new_colnames <- ifelse(!is.na(logo_name_match$logo),logo_name_match$logo, logo_name_match$cols)
        colnames(testmatrixnew) <- new_colnames
    testmatrixnew})
    output$myTable = renderDataTable({
    myData = myData()
    datatable(myData, escape = FALSE)})}


#and also I created the same datatable based on the checkboxgroup input
here is the code

    library(shiny)
    library(DT)
    library(readxl)
    library(dplyr)
    library(formattable)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(shinythemes)

    ui <- fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("yeti"),
               dashboardPage(
                  dashboardHeader(title = "title", titleWidth = 230), 
                  dashboardSidebar(),
                  dashboardBody(fluidRow(
                    checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Pick",
                                       names(testmatrixnew), selected =     names(testmatrixnew),inline = TRUE),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")))))
    server <- function(input, output) {
    mydata2 = testmatrixnew[sample(nrow(testmatrixnew)), ]
      output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
        DT::datatable(mydata2[, input$show_vars, drop = FALSE],options =     list(pageLength = 15, lengthChange = FALSE,dom = 't'))})}

#separately, I created this checkboxgroup input using this code

    brands <- c("kia", "opel", "bmw")

    logos <- c( "https://www.logospng.com/images/88/royal-azure-blue-kia-icon-    free-car-logo-88484.png",
            "https://i.wheelsage.org/pictures/opel/autowp.ru_opel_logo_1.jpg",
            "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/bmw-4-202746.png")
    ui <- fluidPage(checkboxGroupInput("brands", "Brands",
    choiceNames = mapply(brands, logos, FUN = function(brand,     logoUrl) {tagList(tags$img(src=logoUrl, width=20))}, SIMPLIFY = FALSE,     USE.NAMES = FALSE),choiceValues = brands,inline = TRUE))

MDg4J08Mlb_1A3DEmwX4DyNfU/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: 1st snippet doesn't have UI. 2nd one returns `Error in checkboxGroupInput("show_vars", "Pick", names(testmatrixnew),  : 
  object 'testmatrixnew' not found`. Google drive `Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.`

Comment: Dear @A.Suliman thanks for your usual support, updated

Comment: Dear @A.Suliman, in this example we control the columns appearance by the checkboxes, what if we transposed the table and need to control rows by checkboxes please what's the needed amendment, tried several methods without success

Comment: please see my update 'change the _output$myTable_ with the old one'. Also, I fixed a closing bracket in the `ui` that I forgot yesterday.

Comment: Everything works like a charm , I am very grateful for any help :)

Comment: Any time Dear ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `grep` to match `input$brands` with *myData* column names

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
brands <- c("kia", "opel", "bmw")
logos <- c( "https://www.logospng.com/images/88/royal-azure-blue-kia-icon-free-car-logo-88484.png",
        "https://i.wheelsage.org/pictures/opel/autowp.ru_opel_logo_1.jpg",
        "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/bmw-4-202746.png")
ui <- fluidPage(theme=shinytheme("yeti"),
                dashboardPage(
                  dashboardHeader(title = "title", titleWidth = 230), 
                  dashboardSidebar(),
                  dashboardBody(fluidRow(
                    checkboxGroupInput("brands", "Brands",
                                       choiceNames = mapply(brands, logos, FUN = function(brand,logoUrl) {tagList(tags$img(src=logoUrl, width=20))}, 
                                                            SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE),
                                       choiceValues = brands, 
                                       inline = TRUE,
                                       #All values i.e. brands will be initially/pre selected. 
                                       #With brands[1] the first value in brands will be pre selected. 
                                       #selected = brands             
                                       ),
                    DT::dataTableOutput("myTable")))))
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  logoList = data.frame(
    name = c("opel", "kia", "bmw"),
    logo = c(
      "<img height='50' title= 'opel'     src='https://i.wheelsage.org/pictures/opel/autowp.ru_opel_logo_1.jpg'></img>",
      "<img height='50' src='https://www.logospng.com/images/88/royal-azure-    blue-kia-icon-free-car-logo-88484.png'></img>",
      "<img height='50' src='https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/bmw-    4-202746.png'></img>" ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  myData = reactiveVal( {
    logo_name_match <- merge(
      x = data.frame(
        row_id = 1:length(colnames(testmatrixnew)),
        cols = colnames(testmatrixnew), 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
      y = logoList, 
      by.x = "cols", 
      by.y = "name", 
      all.x = TRUE)
    logo_name_match <- logo_name_match[with(logo_name_match, order(row_id)),]
    new_colnames <- ifelse(!is.na(logo_name_match$logo),logo_name_match$logo, logo_name_match$cols)
    colnames(testmatrixnew) <- new_colnames
    testmatrixnew})
  observe(print(myData()))  #To see what we're working with
  output$myTable = renderDataTable({
    req(input$brands) #Show the Table only after one box at least is checked 
    myData = myData()
    #browser()
    #DT::datatable(myData, escape = FALSE)
    col_names = grep(paste(input$brands,collapse = '|'), names(myData), value = TRUE)
    DT::datatable(myData[, c('brand', col_names), drop = FALSE], options = list(pageLength = 15, lengthChange = FALSE,dom = 't'), escape = FALSE)
    })}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## Data

```
#Using dput
testmatrixnew <- structure(list(brand = c("generation_x", "generation_y", "generation_z"
), kia = c(80, 94, 37), vw = c(59, 4, 66), mit = c(56, 1, 72), 
bmw = c(64, 7, 37), audi = c(98, 47, 2), lw = c(91, 99, 32
), lada = c(92, 34, 19), RR = c(55, 68, 88), opel = c(67, 
81, 49), LBGN = c(85, 69, 83), Jeep = c(56, 97, 43)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

## Update

```
output$myTable = renderDataTable({
    req(input$brands) #Show the Table only after one box at least is checked 
    myData = myData()
    #browser()
    #DT::datatable(myData, escape = FALSE)
    #Transpose myData to myData_trans
    #Here is simple example you can run R console using testmatrixnew
    #t_testm <- data.frame(cbind(colnames(testmatrixnew)[-1], t(testmatrixnew[,-1])), row.names = NULL)
    #names(t_testm) <- c('brand','generation_x','generation_y','generation_z')
    myData_trans <- data.frame(cbind(colnames(myData)[-1], t(myData[,-1])), row.names = NULL)
    names(myData_trans) <- c('brand','generation_x','generation_y','generation_z')
    #Match input$brands with column brand
    rw_names <- grep(paste(input$brands,collapse = '|'), myData_trans$brand)
    DT::datatable(myData_trans[rw_names, , drop = FALSE], options = list(pageLength = 15, lengthChange = FALSE,dom = 't'), escape = FALSE)
  })
```